# Ember.js property bindings not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am having trouble using `Ember.computed.alias` to bind to a property of an object. Below is the code snippet.

Code

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var book = Em.Object.create({
    title: 'Just For Fun',
    author: Em.Object.create({
      name: 'Linus Torvalds'
    }),
    authorName: Ember.computed.alias('author.name')
  });

  // expected "Linus Torvalds", actual: dump of some object (perhaps author)
  console.log('Before author name change:', book.get('authorName'));

  book.get('author').set('name', 'Linus Torvalds & David Diamond');

  // expected "Linus Torvalds & David Diamond", actual: dump of some object (perhaps author)
  console.log('After author name change:', book.get('authorName'));

})();
```

I'd like to auto-update `authorName` whenever `name` inside `author` changes.

Please help me understand what I am missing.

Comment: Looks like even `Ember.computed.oneWay` does not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using Object.extend and then creating the object

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var Book = Em.Object.extend({
    title: 'Just For Fun',
    author: Em.Object.create({
      name: 'Linus Torvalds'
    }),
    authorName: Ember.computed.alias('author.name')
  });

  var book = Book.create();
  // expected "Linus Torvalds", actual: dump of some object (perhaps author)
  console.log('Before author name change:', book.get('authorName'));

  book.get('author').set('name', 'Linus Torvalds & David Diamond');

  // expected "Linus Torvalds & David Diamond", actual: dump of some object (perhaps author)
  console.log('After author name change:', book.get('authorName'));

})();
```

Comment: Interesting! That seems to work! But I do not understand why. Is it not possible to create `Ember.Object` instances and use property bindings?

Comment: I am not sure, I tried searching for an explanation but didn't find anything